# My Apache had this error and wont start I have this error (AH00526) if I want to start apache2 in my ubuntu vps

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4

(user):/etc/apache2/conf.d# sudo bash -c '. /etc/apache2/envvars ; apache2'
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/.209.159.151.121.conf.swp:
Invalid command 'b0nano', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: The message tells you exactly what the problem is. I suggest you read it over again, and then fix the syntax error on line 1 of `/etc/apache2/conf.d/.209.159.151.121.conf.swp`, wher eyou have the invalid command 'b0nano'.

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were editing the file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/209.159.151.121.conf`, and either vim is still open (or was, at the time you tried to start apache), or it crashed and left behind its swap file.

Either cd into `/etc/apache2/conf.d` and `vi -r 209.159.151.121.conf` to recover the file and figure out if you need to save it, or just remove the `.209.159.151.121.conf.swp` file.